# Change dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to dd/mm/yyyy using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, date

Need help :)

I need your help to change the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to dd/mm/yyyy using VBA so I don't have to do it manually everytime.

StartDateTime

```
05/07/2017 07:17:44
30/06/2017 23:44:46
30/06/2017 23:16:03
30/06/2017 23:02:33
01/07/2017 09:56:38
30/06/2017 23:15:50
01/07/2017 10:45:53
01/07/2017 12:18:01
01/07/2017 13:14:53
01/07/2017 14:06:37
01/07/2017 11:57:16
01/07/2017 15:12:39
01/07/2017 12:03:47
```

Thank you

---

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro? It's literally just `Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`

Comment: You can just format the whole column at once. No need for VBA or doing it one by one.

Comment: To expand on what @braX said, all you need to do is (1) highlight the whole column then (2) in the Home tab, in the Number group in the drop down, change the format to "Short Date".

Comment: If you want to actually change the value and remove the time portion then you can use `=INT(A1)` and then format as everyone has suggested.

Comment: @dwirony how and where can I apply this Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in formatting it using VBA, here is a great resource that can help you directly from the [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) *VBA Language Reference* webpage. From here you can either format it using the entire range, or you can loop through your data. Below are some great references to get you started

[Formatting by range](http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/formatting-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba/)

[How to use loops](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

Try these methods out, and if you're still having issues, come back and we can help with your code

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing back to me but I really don't know how to do it, because I never worked used VBA before. Currently I am selecting whole range c:c and using replace option to replace the whole range ( *) to short date and then changing dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to dd/mm/yyyy. I thought VBA might change the range automatically whenever I opened the excel or add new entries in the cell. I am sorry but no clue about VBA :(

Comment: Unfortunately, most people here on SO won't provide you code to it... Maybe it might be best for you to do a little research? There are tons of tutorials and resources online that you can utilize that can help you with what you need

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning the formatted result to a cell, as is, then it will likely re-format itself to the original format due to the cell format.

You can change the format of the cell (or the entire column if your data is in a single column) to display in your desired format.

Select the column, open the context menu from the header and select "Format Cells".

In the dialog that opens, select "custom" in the category list then on the right hand side select your desired format from the list.

Edit:
As for the original question, you need the `Format()` function.

Comment: Thanks mate, thats what I am doing manually but I am looking for something whenver I open the workbook, cell format will change as I am expected instead of changing manually. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
`DateValue(Range("A1"))`
```

That is a built in function that will do the trick in most cases.